# How to search if all the values in an array in present in a cell, using vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have an array of names stored in column a in Sheet 2. Say John, Smith, Bob, Peter, William. I need to check a cell in Sheet 1 and see what name is comes last in that cell.

Suppose the content in Sheet1, A1 is "William came home early. Smith rang the bel and Bob opened the door to see if that was Peter". In this, my requirement are, which all names contained in this sentence in A1 cell and whose name came last in this. Obviously it's Peter and I need it to be returned using vba.

I have written a macro using InStrRev function and using MyNames array which contains the names. However it searches the name in array in descending order only.

```
InStrRev(Range("t" & r).Value, MyNames(t), -1, vbTextCompare)
```

Comment: Please post more of the code.  I don't think your problem is in that one line.

Comment: Vivek, Please do not **radically** change the meaning of the question as it invalidates the currently provided answers. Consider asking a new question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function to return the last used name.

The function works as a Worksheet function or VBA as it returns a String(name)

```
Function LastUsedName(rng As Range) As String

    Dim names As Variant
    names = Sheets(2).Range("A1:A" & Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    Dim cell As Range, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Split(rng, Chr(32))

    For j = UBound(arr) To LBound(arr) Step -1
        For i = LBound(names) To UBound(names)
            If names(i, 1) = arr(j) Then
                LastUsedName = names(i, 1)
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next i
    Next j

End Function
```

so

Sheet1 cell A1

[image]

Sheet2 column A

[image]

if you stick the function name in any cell then

[image]

Comment: Thank You! This works fine. However it is not working when the names contain both first and second names. May be because you used Char 32 in between. Could you please correct this so that I can use this even if the name contains multiple part?

Comment: I think that my answer answers your original question. If you have a new question consider asking a new one @VivekS.Panicker

Comment: I just updated and accepted your answer. Would you mind updating your answer so that it won't duplicate question and save space?

Comment: it wouldn't be a duplicate question @VivekS.Panicker Such an edit changes the meaning of how to interpret the question. The code I've given you would need to be modified quite a lot which changes the original meaning of the answer and invalidates it. Bear in mind that you need to demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved while posting a new question.

Comment: Done, please see question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637766/macro-to-find-if-all-values-in-an-array-is-present-in-a-selected-cell)

Answer (score 0):

you need to store the return value from that function somewhere, and then return the value that corresponds to the last position.

I'm assuming you're using `t` to loop through the names.

add in these lines:

```
dim BigPos as long
dim BigLoc as long
dim CurrentPos as long
```

then alter your loop to actually remember which was the name it found furthest along the string

```
BigPos=0
BigLoc=0 ' set to zero, so no old checks can be found

for t=lbound(MyNames) to ubound(MyNames)
    currentpos=InStrRev(Range("t" & r).Value, MyNames(t), -1, vbTextCompare)
    if currenpos>bigpos then 
        'found one of the names *and* 
        'it's further along than the previous found name
        bigpos=currentpos 'remember where in the string we found the text
        bigloc=t 'and remember which name
    end if
next t 'check them all, so there's no exit out of the for loop
```

then you can display the result:

```
if bigloc=0 then 
    msgbox "No names found"
else
    msgbox "Name " & MyNames(bigloc) & " found at character " & bigpos
end if
```